# Finding a value from within a List of Dictionary objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have what can potentially be a very large list of Dictionary objects that I will need to find a particular value from a key. I can certainly do something like

```
foreach(Dictionary<long, string> t in Foo)
{
    if (t.TryGetValue(key, out name))
        break;
}
```

and this will happily iterate through Foo until it finds the key or the foreach ends.

To speed this up, I'd prefer to use a small amount of LINQ. If this was a normal list, I'd be ok, but as this is a List of Dictionary objects, I'm not too sure how it's done.

Help or advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to make the code faster or shorter? Your code is already as fast as you can get.

Comment: Note that LINQ doesn't really place very nice with `out` parameters, so not only will using LINQ made it (marginally) slower, it'll likely be uglier as well.  The only real issue with your code is you have no way of knowing if you broke out of the loop or if you couldn't find the key in any dictionary.

Comment: Is the key only contained in one of the dictionaries in Foo? Or can it be in multiple dictionaries?

Comment: I agree with the others. Your code is (a) short, (b) readable and (c) about as efficient as you can make it. I'd leave it alone! (I assume `name` is initialised to null so you'll know it wasn't found?)

Comment: how very often you need to find?

Comment: How many dictionaries do you have and where are they being populated. If you have a bottleneck and *this* is where (to that point: *have you measured?*), then you will probably make more headway dealing with getting/creating the dictionaries themselves. Create a better design *there*, and you can then arrive at a better solution *here*.

Comment: I don't think that one can state that this code already is as fast as possible without knowing the amount of keys in Foo. There might easily be an advantage in using some threading here - e.g. via PLINQ or a "manual" implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have written the most efficient version of what you want to do.  Since Linq doesn't play nicely with output parameters, it will take slightly longer.  But here is how you would do it:

```
var dict = Foo.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ContainsKey(key));
if (dict != null) { dict.TryGetValue(key, out name); }
```

Comment: Note this will throw an exception if the key is in no dictionary; the OP's code does not.

Comment: I have fixed it so that it no longer throws an error when the key is not in the dictionary

Comment: Thanks for this one. It is a simple List<Dictionary<long,string>> which could have anything upto 60,000 Dictionary objects in. I was unaware that LINQ wasn't a happy bunny with out values.

Comment: Read Eric Lippert on why out parameters and Linq do not mix: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/08/14/out-parameters-and-linq-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it be: `if (dict != null)` instead? In the current code, you invoke `TryGetValue` only if the `dict` is null, causing a NullRefException.

Answer (score 3):

This code will be shorter, but will take just a tiny bit longer:

```
var dictWithKey = Foo.First(d => d.ContainsKey(key));
name = dictWithKey[key];
```

The real question, though, is why you're using a list of dictionaries for this, especially since you say you want "to speed this up." That tells me it's probably something your code will do more than once, right?

A more appropriate approach would probably be to keep a single dictionary that contains all of the key/value pairs, so you can do a single lookup rather than iterating through multiple dictionaries.

Comment: Note this will throw an exception if the key is in no dictionary; the OP's code does not.

Comment: That's true. The OP wasn't clear about what valid expectations are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on the amount of dictionaries in `Foo` there might be an advantage in using Parallel LINQ (PLINQ) instead:

```
string name = null;
Parallel.ForEach(foo, f =>
                      {
                          if (name != null)
                              return;

                          if (f.ContainsKey(key))
                              name = f[key];
                      });
```

The implementation assumes that the given key maps to the same value OR that the key is unique across all dictionaries. Also it is assumed that the value is not null.

With 5,000,000 dictionaries containing one key and one value this runs about 150 ms faster than your original implementation.

Benchmarks (2.4GHz Intel Core i5 with two physical cores and two virtual cores):

- PLINQ: 89ms
- Original solution: 250ms

However, I want to stress that PLINQ is not necessarily always the answer to getting things run faster. In some cases where you have code that uses parallel foreach loops to traverse few elements, the actual cost of starting the threads in the background is actually much much more expensive than just iterating using a simple for loop - so, use it when there are many elements to iterate through :)

Comment: The only way those two code snippets would compile is if there's a variable scoped at or above the parallel loop, thus the results will fight with each other for who wins, and you're unlikely to get the correct result.

Comment: @Servy If the key maps to the same value OR the key is unique across all dictionaries, then, how can this give a wrong result? :) If the search key is used in multiple dictionaries, and maps to different values, then yes, there will be a race (but as far as I can tell, the OP has not stated this somewhere?)

Comment: All `out` parameters *must* be set within the body of the method; this means that every dictionary that doesn't find a value sets `name` to be `null` (or theoretically some other meaningless value, but in practice it'll be the default).  So whichever is executed last is what will set the final value of `name`.  If it's a dictionary that has a value, it'll work. If a dictionary without a value is executed later, that value will be wiped out.

Comment: @Servy you're 100% right - I did not take into account that the `out` parameter of course MUST be set. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated code sample and text.

Comment: You're now doing the lookup twice whenever you've found a value.  Your *real* problem is actually that you're not properly rolling up the results of each iteration; you're setting a shared variable, and that's simply not appropriate.  Instead have each iteration generate it's result entirely locally and then rely on the appropriate parallelization framework techniques for aggregating them.  i.e. `var value = Foo.AsParallel().First(dic => dic.ContainsKey(key))[key];`  (For proper error handling use code in OP with the `AsParallel` added in.)

Comment: I see your point, and I think it is valid. In terms of benchmarks, I just want to add that your suggestion gives me, on average, an execution at 140ms. That is a bit more expensive than my PLINQ solution. I know the lookup is done twice, but since that operation is quite cheap, it does not affect the throughout significantly. Anyway, thanks for your input, I'm glad that you have taken your time to explain where things can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

You have the key setup as a long type.

```
long key = 1;
Dictionary<long, string> name = foo.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(key)).First();
```

Comment: 1) This is only looking through one dictionary, not a list of them. 2) This is doing a linear search; dictionaries are specifically designed to be efficiently searched; you aren't allowing for that.

Comment: I missed that it was a list of Dictionary objects. Fixed now.